# Trying to connect my lav microphone to my android, only recognized as headphones

Tags: microphone

I have a pixel 6 and a deity v lav. I connect the lav microphone to a 3.5mm to usbc adapter then connect them both to my phone. My phone recognizes the deity v lav as an external headphone instead of a microphone

When I do the exact same thing but connect it to my computer instead there's no issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the USB-C adapter capable of processing microphone signals or does it only support headphones?

Comment: I can get the microphone to work if I use opencamera and force external microphone but I want to use gcam :(

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screenshot of Google Camera]

What do you exactly mean when saying that your phone only recognizes your microphone as headphones?
On my phone (Google Pixel 4a) with my headphones, I am able to select the headphones as microphone as follows:

- Plug in headphones
- Start Google Camera
- Switch to video
- Hit the settings gear icon on the top
- The last setting in the popup allows selecting the headphones as microphone, as seen on the picture.

Did you already try those steps? If yes, and it still didn't work, I don't think that there's anything that can be done.